# IIS does not allow run .exe file using excec command on PHP

Tags: php, iis, exec, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have a code on PHP that was working in a server but we migrate that code to another server and now that code is not working, specifically we want to run an .exe file using PHP with the instruction exec

I debug the script and it looks be working properly and the IUSR user and IIS_IUSR have the correct permissions and actually the exe file is running, but, when it run it need generate some files that is the part that cause the issues, the program are trying to create files on the AppPool directory for example like this:
C:\MyPath\somewebsite.com\8áª\MyProgram\

Where C:\MyPath\somewebsite.com\ is the AppPool root directory and MyProgram\ is the directory that the app is creating

Where \8áª is generated randomly and changes all the time that we try to run the program, debugging with Process Monitor I can get an error: PATH NOT FOUND and/or NAME INVALID, on the previous server we modify the user on the IIS to run the script (that was on IIS 6 now we are on IIS 8.5) and that files was created on the home directory of the user AND without the random directory, for example:
C:\Users\MyUser\MyProgram\

where MyUser is the user that we assigned, but on that new server we get the files on the AppPool directory no matter if we change the user

I think that we can solve that if we was able to define a path for the IUSR user and set it as "home" path but I cannot found where to modify the IUSR user, I know that is a build-in user that IIS create but I'm not sure if I can edit that settings for that user.

I already mention that we used IIS but just as an extra data, we are running that over Windows Server 2012 R2

Any suggestion?

Comment: by the way, the exe file that we are trying to run was developed for a third part developer so we cannot change it, and we cannot "remove" that files that are created or move his location using parameters

Answer (score 0):

You topic / question is:

> IIS does not allow run .exe file using excec command on PHP

which is the correct behavior! You don't want to run .exe files through PHP, really. You have to give the IUSR execute permissions on cmd.exe first, meany you might as well give all your virtual users administrator permissions.

Comment: as I mention, the permissions are ok, administrator permissions are not necessary, if you set the "execution" permission should work

Comment: Your website's authentication is set to a specified user (IUSR), or application pool identity? And your application pool's identity is set to a built-in account or custom account?

Comment: I tried both, any of them are working, also I create an specific user and assign it to the IIS and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

lot of time after but, PHP side was ok, the problem was on the .exe file, the exe file create some files that was used for the same exe program, but it uses relative paths so when the process run makes that did not found the files generated and this caused the errors